# Google Charts,PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(load_chart_data);

function load_chart_data() {
 $.ajax({
    url: "serv.php", 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON", 
    data: {get_chart: true},
    success: function(chart_values) {
      draw_chart(chart_values); 
    }
 });
}

function drawChart(chart_values) {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);

   var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new     google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>

<div id="chart2"></div>
```

and this is my serv.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['get_chart'])) {
$values = array(
    array('Task', 'Hours Per Day'),
    array('Work', 11),
    array('Eat', 2),
    array('Commute', 2),
    array('Watch TV', 2),
    array('Sleep', 7),
 );

 echo json_encode($values);
}
?>
```

This code have to create a Google Chart, but something is wrong. Please,  help. Interesting to note, that json works and the array from serv.php have loaded

Comment: Try add header in php page 
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @user1978142 can you look this?

Comment: Where can I look ?

Comment: @Ahmad Rezk Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @Ahmad Rezk "Try add header in php page header('Content-Type: application/json');" - no result

Comment: Is your code include `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` ?

Comment: @Ahmad Rezk yes

Comment: Are you sure you included JQuery library ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why but this code is working (but it is a LineChart - not AreaChart ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(load_chart_data);

function load_chart_data() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'serv.php', 
      type: 'POST',
      data: {get_chart: true},
      dataType: 'JSON', 
      success: function(chart_values) {
         draw_chart(chart_values); 
      }
    });
 }

function draw_chart(chart_values) {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);
var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    vAxis: {title: 'Hours Per Day', titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
    hAxis: {title: 'Task', titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response in success you called **draw_chart** function

```
success: function(chart_values) {
  draw_chart(chart_values); 
}
```

And you defined `function drawChart(chart_values) {` There's a diff. between **drawChart** and **draw_chart** :)

Your chart is here : [image]